# Redeploy a branch in a site with the latest git commit using Netlify API

Tags: deployment, bitbucket, netlify, cicd, gridsome

I use Gridsome for Static Site Generation and I integrated Bitbucket with Netlify, so when I add a new commit it directly redeploys my site with the latest commit.
Sometimes I need to redeploy without any changes in the project files, just to get the latest changes in the Database.

I want to add a button to my site when click, it uses Netlify API for redeploying with the latest Git commit, How can I do that with Netlify API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the same behavior of redeploying with last commit or last deploy
[image]

First, I have to get the last deploy id for this branch

```
   const deploys = await this.$axios.get(`https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/sites/***siteId***/deploys?page=1&per_page=1&branch=***branchName***`, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
      }
   });
```

Then we retry this specific deployment with this code.

```
    await this.$axios.post(`https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/deploys/${deploys.data[0].id}/retry`, {}, {
      headers
    })
```